# How would I modify the code to make it possible to download multiple files

Tags: swift3, nsurlsession

please i have an question for how can i make multiple download files at the same time in swift 3
i can only download one file but how can i do multiple download files and each file can i control on it like pause ,resume and progress view in the table view cell

the following code for download one file :

```
fun loadMp3() {
        let videoMp3 = "http://www.example.com"
        let url = URL(string: videoMp3)
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
            (data,response,error) in
            if error == nil {

                if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    if response.statusCode == 200 {

                        if data != nil {

                            do {
                                let responseOfJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                                let getLink = responseOfJson?["link"] as! String

                                let getVideo = URL(string: getLink)
                                print("Downloading...")
                                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                        let getData = try! Data(contentsOf: getVideo!)
                                        self.progressBar.setProgress(Float(getData.count), animated: true)
                                        let fileManager = FileManager.default
                                        let document = try! fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                                        let file = document.appendingPathComponent("WadaetAlhussien.mp3")

                                        try! getData.write(to: file)

                                        print(file)



                                    }
                                }

                            }catch {
                                print(error)
                            }



                        }

                    }
                }


            }

        })
        task.resume()

    }
```

thanks all

Comment: Aaaand what is your question here?

Comment: how can i download multiple files at the same time? this code is download one file only i need to give the user ability to download 10 files for example at the same time and each file have progress view and can pause or resume each file separately

Comment: Then put that into your question. Something like "How would I modify the code to make it possible to download multiple files". However this is not the correct place to ask for code modifications...

Comment: thank you very much